# Convert TFLite to Lite

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a working app with TFlite using tensorflow for poets. It works with a labels.txt and graph.lite pair files. I have downloaded another model in .tflite file format and wanted to use in my application. I wanted to ask what are the differences between .lite and .tflite files and are there any ways to convert tflite format to lite?
Thanks

Comment: Have you found answers to your questions?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in ".lite" and ".tflite" format (as long as they can be correctly consumed by Tensonflow Lite). And there is no need to convert them.