# What is the difference between the .lite and the .tflite formats

Tags: android, firebase, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

What is the difference between the `.lite` and the `.tflite` formats (TensorFlow formats)? And if there is no difference, why there are two of them?

In addition to the question, it seems that I can't upload my model with the `.lite` extension file to Firebase ML kit. What might be the reason for that?

Comment: According to this answer there is no difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396671/convert-tflite-to-lite (still looking for a more authoritative source though).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I saw this answer, with all due respect, the answer is not accepted, answered by an unexperienced user and is not backed up by documentation.

Comment: Agreed, hence my comment on looking for a more authoritative source. But it's still polite to link the question, since it's pretty much the same.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen they are similar, but I would argue that they are the same. I agree though that I could have linked it as an additional reference, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ML Developers first train a TensorFlow model, and then use [TOCO](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/README.md) to convert it to TensorFlow Lite model. When running the TOCO command, you can specify whatever output name for the converted Lite model. All TensorFlow Lite TOCO samples use .tflite extension; but .lite seems another popular extension people would like to choose.

So as long as it's a TensorFlow Lite FlatBuffer formatted model, TensorFlow Lite would be able to load / run the model regardless of the extension.

But unfortunately, ML Kit Console at this moment only takes files with .tflite extension. We can consider remove that enforcement. In the meantime, if you are sure it's a TensorFlow Lite model, simply rename the extension and upload it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. IMHO if .lite extension is as good as .tflite and is in use by devs, it will be great to include it as a valid file upload. With that said, I'm still unable to upload my .tflite model, I have contacted Google support and understood that there is a recurring bug ( the files are being uploaded but not saved on the console ), maybe you familiar with some fix for that on my end? And thanks again, I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @RomanRozenshtein Sorry to hear that. Could you elaborate on "the files are being uploaded but not saved on the console"? Did your model pass the upload validation and did you click "Publish" button"?

Comment: OK, so apparently I am an idiot :) I have completely missed the "Publish" button. I have successfully uploaded the model just now, thanks for pointing it out! As an accomplished test monkey, I can suggest to move the button to the context of the model upload (in the gray background  area to right of the "browse" button, after successful upload). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. Firebase will see how to improve the UIs.